# Windows won't recognize Galaxy S2 at all

Tags: android, windows, usb, galaxy

I'm having an issue with my Galaxy S2. I typically leave it in Debug mode, up until a few days ago it has worked great. I've successfully loaded APK's for testing through eclipse previously.

I tried to load a prototype of a new app im working on and when I plugged in the S2 nothing happened, Windows didn't beep like usual and when I tried to view running devices it did not show up.

When I look at the device manager under universal serial bus controllers, it doesn't show any 'unknown devices'

I've tried reinstalling drivers through kies, and third party sources (as well as removing all drivers and letting windows install them again for me.

I've tried connecting as Mass Storage Device, with debug mode on and off.

I've restarted both my computer and phone many times.

When my phone is off and plugged in Windows will beep and say that a device was connected but not recognized (which is more then what I get when the phone is on)

And sometimes when I "troubleshoot connection issues" in Kies it will reinstall the drivers and after the process is complete windows will report "Drivers were not successfully installed"

I've tried plugging it into my Windows XP laptop and it will show up as "Unrecognized device" even after I installed Kies on the laptop, and tried the driver installation it with the same results.

Posting here is my last resort as I've spent close to 5 hours troubleshooting this issue, and searching for answers. My biggest concern is that when I do plug my phone in it will beep to say that it is charging, but windows 7 doesnt even see it!

I appreciate all suggestions & help!

EDIT: Also I installed the [Samsung Android USB Driver for Windows](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9480&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fdown%2Fcnts%2FtoolSDK.list.do%3FplatformId%3D1%26indexType%3D1%26indexDirection%3D1%26sortType%3D0%26cateId%3D1025%26codeType%3DAll%26searchText%3D%26curPage%3D2%26listLines%3D%26formData%3Dnumber1%26nacode%3D&nacode=) and windows reports that the drivers were not successfully installed

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Have you tried to restart the adb server in a console?

Comment: I have, but right now the phone won't even connect to the computer let alone the adb server.

Comment: sorry for necroing the post, but have you tried installing the latest version of android SDK?  I had that problem at one point when my SDK was out of date.

Answer (score 8):

Try to key in dialer:

```
*#7284#
```

It has 4 options:

> UART

- MODEM
- PDA

> USB

- MODEM
- PDA

In USB section, select the PDA. If it already selected to PDA then reselect it by selecting MODEM and then PDA again.

Only change the USB setting and then press back and try reconnect to kies again.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and JUST as i was about to give up, i realized that I had replaced my usb cord with a generic one from the store. I happened to still have the old one around still and that ended up being my issue -.-; Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I would have never believed this could have been the problem. The defective cord was charging my phone and appeared normal in every other way.

Comment: I have so many USB connectors/chargers from different devices that I lost track which is which... :-(.

Answer (score 2):

This really sucks, I know I've had this happen a few times and it's really annoying to have to deal with. I had luck with this [post](http://androidforums.com/htc-hero/41485-usb-device-not-recognized.html) where they suggest:

> ... they suggested removing battery from hero with usb pluged in and
>   then putting battery back in, so i did this thinking it wouldn't work
>   and hey presto, mounting option became available. I was then able to
>   follow your first set of intructions to install the drivers through
>   devices and sync is now working!

If that doesn't work there are a few suggestions and helpful driver websites on there for you to follow :-D

**I know I would:**

1. Uninstall all drivers related to your device
2. Restart Computer without connected
3. Pull battery on device, plug it in, and once detected put battery back in.
4. If driver doesn't install correctly, or "unknown device", go to the website on that forum to get the CORRECT driver for your device and Windows OS
5. Go to Control Panel->Device Manager->(unknown device)->Update Driver
6. Locate downloaded driver, install
7. Make sure that when connected, the device says "USB Connected" in it's notification area
8. Click "Turn on USB storage", or "USB Debugging -> USB debugging"

**.. this will at least show you that you have the right drivers.**

IF you did all of this and you still can't get it to debug through eclipse, you either have conflicting drivers somehow, or your eclipse IDE isn't setup properly. Maybe update Eclipse, and Android SDK and try again?

Sorry can't give you exact details but this problem could be ANYTHING lol

Comment: I was really frustrated by this... removing the battery seems like voodoo if you're rebooting anyway, but it does work.

Comment: @jnnnnn: Yeah it seems stupid, but sometimes my device freezes when trying to communicate over USB with eclipse/adb... I have to wind up removing the battery to even reboot lol.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I tried what you recommend, doing a battery pull while USB was plugged in and still nothing happened on the computer, no detection, no 'unknown device' shows up in the device manager... :(

Comment: Just tried resetting to factory defaults still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using a generic cord. 
[Don't use for usb transfert](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fvp3rjudcu5q0e/2013-12-10%2008.55.47.jpg)
I think they are made only for charging.

Solve by using a stock cord not a generic one.

Comment: @kleopatra it's not a link only answer. The link is just to a picture of a cord. There is information in the answer - I rearranged it a little to make that more obvious

Comment: This worked for me. I think my case was that the cable had a broken wire but the charging lines still worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after talking to Samsung they informed me that there is a small defect with the female usb connection, and that it can sometimes be loose.

Only solution, mail it to them...

Answer (score 0):

This fix works on all my computers that "don't recognize" my rooted Samsung Android. Plug the phone into the computer and restart phone. When it comes up again, the computer recognizes it.

Answer (score 0):

My method is `KIES AIR.`

Open `Kies Air`

Go to `settings > Bluetooth off` set. 
`More settings > Tethering and portable hot spot > Bluetooth tethering` check true and portable Wi-Fi hotspot check true.

Now KIES air open on your device and start button click. copy IP address to browser

Your s2 is connected your computer.

Open browser, and copied ip then click paste.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Win XP SP3 workstations that would not connect to my Galaxy. Finally fixed it by installing this particular [Intel driver](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices) and installing Windows Media Player 11.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running a custom kernel on your phone, you may want to check too if you have "force fast charge" turned on or not.  I thought my phone and computer would never talk to each other again but it turned out I had fast charge enabled.  Turning that off solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with USB 3.0 ports. I was tormented by this issue too and I was at the point where I was so ready to burn this device to kingdom come. Before I did that, I decided to use my never-used 2.0 port and guess what, IT WORKED! If your PC doesn't have a 2.0, good luck with that.

Answer (score -1):

punch in code *#7284#, (UART set to PDA) and (USB set to PDA)
solved my problem